# IP Filter via Firewall vs /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Tags: linux, security, firewall, sshd

Typically I just use a local firewall (FirewallD, UFW, IPTables) on my personal linux boxes. At my work, we use Jamf (previously Casper suite) to managed our Macs, which uses SSH (remote login) for some of its tasks. Recently I realized that all of our clients were technically exposed to getting SSH brute forced via the jamf management account (even though it would take centuries for a computer to guess it, except maybe the fact that hackers would have many clients to test out the same account on) because of their public IPs. To resolve this, I decided the easiest way was to add a one liner to the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, `AllowedUsers *@x.x.*.*`, to all of out macs.

Now this has me questioning, for Linux boxes, firewall vs sshd_config, is one way better than the other?

Comment: Suppose sshd had a nasty vulnerability (quite possible!)    By employing blocking at the firewall level, you'd perhaps prevent bad actors even reaching sshd ?